# Can one water plants before Shacharit?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, zemanim, priorities

Would one be permitted to water plants or feed pets (as another example), before saying shacharit, or would it be better to say shacharit first?

Comment: There is a famous story about the Arizal, he banned someone from coming to his shiurim. Eventually the person confronted him and asked why and the Arizal said "I was hoping you would contemplate the matter and figure it out for yourself, but every day you go to shacharit without feeding your chickens, and Hashem can't hear you over their cries of hunger". This behaviour clearly contradicted the Arizal's teaching but he was welcome back in the shiur once he started feeding his chickens before shacharit. I'll find a source bli neder

Comment: @RabbiKaii I think that story is somewhere in Shar HaMitzvot

Answer (score 3):

If they need the food and there is a worry of צער בעלי חיים one should do it before tefillah like anything one is allowed to do before tefillah which is for mitzvah purposes, but if it's not going to be צער בעלי חיים one shouldn’t do it before tefillah. With regarding plants there is no idea of צער בעלי חיים and there wouldn't a mitzvah to water them.

This is my source: https://din.org.il/2021/11/14/%D7%94%D7%90%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%AA-%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99-%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%99-%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%99-%D7%90%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA/#